# Saving function in java creating new column instead of overriding

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, save

So I'm coding a program in Java that allows me to create teams (also remove them and edit them).

After creating a team the program enables the user to add 10 players, define their weight and tries scored and once again remove and edit them. Now as soon as they reach 10 players they lose the ability of adding more and a save button is enabled.

The problem I'm having is: if I save a team and then edit it or remove it and I try to save it again, the table creates another column and moves all the values one column to the right. The images will illustrate a bit better what I mean.

When saved for first time:
[image: When saved for first time]

After saving 2nd time:
[image: After saving 2nd time]

The code for the saving function is at follows:

```
private void btn_SaveTeamActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
  DefaultTableModel pattern  = (DefaultTableModel) table_PlayerBoard.getModel();

  try {
        saveTable((String) table_LeaderBoard.getValueAt(table_LeaderBoard.getRowCount() - 1, 0));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mainpage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }

  enableTeamEdit();
  btn_SaveTeam.setEnabled(false);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Team Saved");

  pattern.setRowCount(0);
  btn_RankTeams.setEnabled(true);
  counter = 0;
}                                            

ArrayList <Integer> triesList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList <String> teamList = new ArrayList();
boolean check = false;
```

I can't really understand where is the mistake. If there is any more information needed let me know. Thanks in advance.

saveTable method:

```
public void saveTable(String fileName)throws Exception  {
    DefaultTableModel chart  = (DefaultTableModel) table_PlayerBoard.getModel();  
    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\Desktop\\Sports\\" + fileName + ".txt")); 
    System.out.println(fileName);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < chart.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < chart.getColumnCount();j++)
        {
            bfw.write((chart.getValueAt(i,j).toString()));
            bfw.write("\t");;
        }
        bfw.newLine();
    }
    bfw.close();
}
```

Comment: Please share `saveTable` method.

Comment: @rdonuk just edited so the saveTable is available

Comment: So you want the contents of the save file to be completely overwritten by the new team?

Comment: @Jonah Haney I want the contents of the saved file to be completely overwritten with  any changes the user does to the players, whether is to the tries, names, weight or team name. At the moment I'm able to update them but once I save that happens (2nd image). creates what it seems to be a new column and moves the values of tries to weight and weight to the new column created

Answer (score 0):

In your `saveTable(...)` method, simply delete the contents of the given file, then open a new one for writing like this:

```
 String path = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\Desktop\\Sports\\" + fileName + ".txt";
 File file = new File(path);
 file.delete();
 file = new File(path);

 BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

Comment: Might be a silly question as I'm new to java but when you mean delete the contents you refer to the for statement or to the actual directory after the BufferedWriter? thanks

Comment: without wanting to be a pain I have tried this bit of code in the saveTable method but once again once I press the save button the tries column and Bodyweight column are moved to the right as if in creation of a virtual column. Any idea?